# Deleting multiple Directories in Ant

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant

I want to delete directories from an ant target without hardcoding how many directories there are.  So far I have this:

```
<target name="clean">

    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="${clean.dirs}"/>
            </fileset>
        </delete>

</target>
```

With the properties set as:

```
src.dir=./src
clean.dirs=./com/webservices/resources/jaxws;./com/asdf/entity;./com/asdf/service
```

This doesnt seem to work... What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="${clean.dirs}"/>
</delete>
```

Properties file:-

```
src.dir=./src
clean.dirs=**/com/webservices/resources/jaxws,**/com/asdf/entity,**/com/asdf/service
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... It doesn't seem to be working however... Any idea why?

Comment: Can you draw how your directory structure looks like, and where your ANT file is located at?